# Javascript file changing to html file?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, express

I'm having an issue in my express app. When I connect to the localhost I get an error in my console "uncaught syntax exception on my script.js on line 1. Which I thought was strange so I looked at the file through the sources tab and it looks like it was overwritten as an html file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Note Taker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/4.1.3/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Note Taker
    </a>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div style="margin-top: 80px;" class="jumbotron text-center">
      <h1 class="display-4">Note Taker <span role="img" aria-label="Memo"></span></h1>
      <h4 class="mt-4">Take notes with Express</h4>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mt-4" href="/notes.html" role="button">Get Started</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

this is the output that the console is giving me for script.js which is the exact html for my index.html while my script.js is:

```
var $noteTitle = $(".note-title");
var $noteText = $(".note-textarea");
var $saveNoteBtn = $(".save-note");
var $newNoteBtn = $(".new-note");
var $noteList = $(".list-container .list-group");

// activeNote is used to keep track of the note in the textarea
var activeNote = {};

// A function for getting all notes from the db
var getNotes = function() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "/api/notes",
    method: "GET"
  });
};

// A function for saving a note to the db
var saveNote = function(note) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "/api/notes",
    data: note,
    method: "POST"
  });
};

(this goes on for 100+ lines)
```

I've tried moving the file around in the folder, i have checked my routes and none point to a js file. I've never had an issue like this before so im very confused as to what is happening

Comment: You do have an opening <script> and closing </script> tag correct? Seems silly but I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: Yes, in the top bit of code (which is line for line the html file) right before the close of the body tag the script tag is formatted like so: 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script.js"></script>

Comment: I'm not aware that they would need to if the script is referenced in the html. I'm using jquery to manipulate the DOM and handle events. the express routes would just point to other html pages, I have an api-routes that connect to a JSON file that hold the information. 
When checking the network tab on the dev console it shows that script.js is served it just gets changed to the html of whatever route its on. what exactly would i need to reference in my express routes?

Comment: you will probably need to post the code that serves the static files, or if you have a catch all which is serving your route instead of serving static file for "script.js"